# Will disposing IBM MQ objects (IBM XMS) explicitly call 'close' on these?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I receive and send messages from and to IBM MQ with c#. Currently I use the using directive and call the close-method on all XMS objects which provide it, even they are disposable.

Does anybody know, if I can spare the close-call since dispose will call it implicitly?

If dispose does not call close implicitly, how can I handle that in case of runtime errors? I have cascaded usings, and to write a try/catch for every using is not really a good option.

**Already tried:**

I've read the [IBM documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024064), it says that I have to close **OR** dispose the objects. But is that for sure?

**Sample code:**

Here basically my code:

```cs
//
// ... create and configure iConnectionFactory ...
// ...
//

// Create connection
using (var iConnection = iConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    // Create session
    using (var iSession = iConnection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge))
    {
        // Create destination
        using (var iDestination = iSession.CreateQueue(ActivityConfiguration.AuthSettings.QueueName))
        {
            // Create producer
            using (var iMessageProducer = iSession.CreateProducer(destination))
            {
                // 
                // ... connection start, create message and send message
                // ...
                //

                iMessageProducer.Close(); // needed?
            }
        }
        iSession.Close(); // needed?
    }
    iConnection.Close(); // needed?
}
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Why not use a disassembler like e.g. ILSpy and see by yourself what the Dispose code does?

Comment: By document you can just do one of them, since most likely, they would call Close inside the Dispose, following Dispose pattern is better, you can also implement the Finalizer. Also verify if you can check the impact like post Close / Dispose, the status of the object changes, or number pooled connections change, which will verify your understanding

Comment: Does your code compile, since in their documentation, I don't see Dispose method exposed / IDisposable implemented, check [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/sapimprod.htm)

Comment: When exiting a Using statement a dispose is suppose to automatically occur.  I've seen cases where exceptions in lower modules exits the using without the dispose occurring. I would add an exception handler inside the using to see if an unhandled exception is occurring.

Comment: Both IConnection and ISession implements IDisposable interface. The Dispose method closes the respective objects. So technically speaking explicit call to close is not required.

Comment: You should never rely on default behavior.  If your code opens it then make sure the code closes it.  If your code connects to something then make sure the code disconnects from it.  And make sure it is handled in all conditions including exceptions.  The last thing you want to be doing is reporting a memory link at 3:00AM because the product you are relying on has a bug in it!!

Comment: @Mrinal: Yes, code compiles, the objects in the usings do implement IDisposable. And yes, we're currently using the try and error concept to learn more about the behavior of those objects. But the idea was to spare that, if someone can provide me experienced knowledge...

Comment: @jdweng: the behavior of the using directive is clear. To add a try/catch block on every using scope seems pretty ugly.

Comment: @shashi: yes, I would implement it the same way, if I woild write those classes. But have you proof/source, that it is that was implemented that way?

Comment: @roger: "you should not rely on default behavior" - that's why I ask you :)... the hope was to find someone which either has knowledge by source or by experience... currently does not looks like :)

Comment: @Uwe: Yes in the end, probably I have to reflect the concerning assembly and hopefuly can find out something in there...

Comment: You are getting the exception because of your close.  If you close inside a Using then when the Using tries to do the dispose the object is closed and gives an exception.  If you do not add the try/catch then you are not going to see errors.

Comment: @jdweng: hmm.. I cannot reproduce your described behavior. I can close and dispose afterwards without any issue - did you experienced that behavior? The error message in this case is not an issue at all...

Comment: It may be with different versions of VS (may be bug been fixed)  or different type of ports/streams when you close.

Comment: @jdweng: not sure if you did understand the demand of this thread (no offense, this happens to me too from time to time), or maybe I do not understand you. But Visual Studio, ports and streams are completely outside the scope.